# Making a div smaller than its contents

Tags: html, size, dhtml

I'm trying to show a div on a webpage, with mostly text.

I would like to know if I can make it smaller so that not all the contents are able to be seen so I later on can make it larger using JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, just specify an overflow of hidden.

EG: in CSS:

```
#divid {
   height: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

That'd make it cut it off after 100 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide things using CSS, I'd use display:none or visibility:hidden, not putting them in a div that's too small.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to make it enlarge slowly.